# How to add columns from multiple files in U-SQL in ADLA?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a lot of csv files in a Azure Data Lake, consisting of data of various types (e.g., pressure, temperature, true/false). They are all time-stamped and I need to collect them in a single file according to timestamp for machine learning purposes. This is easy enough to do in Java - start a filestream, run a loop on the folder that opens each file, compares timestamps to write relevant values to the output file, starting a new column (going to the end of the first line) for each file.
While I've worked around the timestamp problem in U-SQL I'm having trouble coming up with syntax that will help me run this on the whole folder. The wildcard syntax {*} treats all files as the same fileset while I need to run some sort of loop to join a column from each file individually.
Is there any way to do this, perhaps using virtual columns?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to think about your problem functional/declaratively and not based on procedural paradigms such as loops.

Let me try to rephrase your question to see if I can help. You have many csv files with data that is timestamped. Different files can have rows with the same timestamp, and you want to have all rows for the same timestamp (or range of timestamps) output to a specific file? So you basically want to repartition the data?

What is the format of each of the files? Do they all have the same schema or different schemas? In the later case, how can you differentiate them? Based on filename?

Let me know in the comments if that is a correct declarative restatement and the answers to my questions and I will augment my answer with the next step.

Comment: Thanks!
Sure, I'm definitely having trouble looking at the problem. 
The format for each file consists of two or three columns. Timestamp - Value - Unit. The unit column may or may not be there (e.g., for True/False fields). Each file is not the same unit/field. For example, one file could be temperature and another air pressure and another true/false. I'm looking to combine these separate files so that each field is a separate column and is coordinated by the closest timestamp. The timestamps are not exactly the same for each file. Am I making sense?

Comment: I do have the same situation, many files, the file name is different and I'm able to come up with one file as an output, however the rows get stacked instead of merged, in other words, it does not care about the  difference of schemas, what would be a good way of merging many files with different schemas so that you merge all of these into one file, assuming that the columns that do not exist in some files, will be NULL or empty.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @AnzahHayat. In your case you could write a custom extractor. If all possible unit/field types are known, you then could write a query of the form: `EXTRACT timestamp DateTime, airpressure int, temperature decimal, … FROM "input\{*}.dat" USING new MyExtractors.Extractor();`


If the fields are not known, you can use a `SqlMap<string, string>` to get the values. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrys/2016/08/15/how-to-deal-with-files-containing-rows-with-different-column-counts-in-u-sql-introducing-a-flexible-schema-extractor/

Comment: The grouping by timestamps can be done in a separate Reducer or windowing functions, depending on the semantics of the grouping.